# Are the vaadin components responsive by default?

Tags: vaadin8

here I am currently working on a project developed by Vaadin Version 8. I use the Valo theme to add style. But I see that there is the setResponsive method which belongs to each component. I would like to know if the components are responsive by default or I have to set them to true
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setResponsive`](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/a17348081abf87cb0d42bef4ae4faac3c8fd6c72/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.java#L1022) method is coming from the `AbstractComponent` class. So any component extending this class has the method. Functionality is implemented as an `AbstractExtension` ([`Responsive`](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/a17348081abf87cb0d42bef4ae4faac3c8fd6c72/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/server/Responsive.java#L155)).

Before setting Responsiveness it's checked if a component has an extension already. Extensions are saved inside the `extensions` field of the [`AbstractClientConnector` class](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/a17348081abf87cb0d42bef4ae4faac3c8fd6c72/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/server/AbstractClientConnector.java#L89), which is empty by default. (`AbstractComponent` also extends `AbstractClientConnector`, so each components extends it as well). None of the components seems to add any default extensions.

Therefore, by default responsiveness is **not enabled**.